# SSL certificates - can they be used on more than one server

Tags: ssl

I have many websites all scattered on different IIS servers but they all accessible via *sitename*.example.co.uk. i.e. site1.example.co.uk

Btw this is only an example so I can get to grips with SSL certificates hence they're all self-signed via the following process

1. Create my own CA
2. Generate key and csr
3. then generate signed certificate

http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/

The resultant certificate of step 3 is assigned to *.example.co.uk.  Can that be used on multiple servers, or do I have create a new certificate + key for each server despite them matching the domain on the certificate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The certificate is a third-party-signed public key, and can be used by anyone with the corresponding private key.  So as long as you give each server the matching private key, it can use the certificate.

But if you're making your own CA, why bother?  You can mint certificates for each server and they will be no less (nor any more) trusted than the one private-CA-signed certificate you're proposing to use everywhere, and you'll have less of a problem with keeping a single private key secure through distribution to, and use on, many endpoints.

Comment: We have a similar situition and have different web sites on different servers belonging to the same domain as site1.abc.com, site2.abc.com, site3.abc.com. So, which steps should we apply in order to use the certificate of abc.com on different IIS servers for these web sites? Could you please clarify us a little bit more?

Comment: @binary That's a different question, so you should ask it as a new question and not as a comment here.

Comment: @MikeScott I think it is exactly the same situation and creating a new question for this issue means that it will be marked as a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @binary You're asking about the details of configuring IIS, so to me it's a new question - though you should probably link to this one to show you're aware of it.  At any rate, I won't use non-free software, so I can't help with IIS config.  Sorry.

Comment: @MadHatter Ok, have a look at [Using the same SSL Certificate of a Domain on different IIS Servers?](http://serverfault.com/questions/764950/using-the-same-ssl-certificate-of-a-domain-on-different-iis-servers) please? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There's no technical reason why you can't use a wildcard SSL certificate for *.example.co.uk on as many servers as you want whose domain names match the wildcard. But some certificate issuers have commercial terms & conditions that limit the number of servers on which the certificate can be used. It's not a technical limit, and the certificate will still work on as many servers as you want; you'll just be in breach of your contract with them if you use it on more servers than you have agreed. Of course that won't apply to your self-signed certificates that you're using to test it out, but it may when you get round to actually obtaining a certificate that's signed by a trusted CA.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing technically prohibiting you from installing a given cert on multiple machines. However, if you were purchasing the cert from a commercial CA then the license agreement probably requires you to pay for each server even if the same cert is installed.

I believe some security / corporate standards discourage high-level wildcard certs (so no *.example.co.uk, but perhaps *.somespecificapp.example.co.uk), to minimize damage if the cert is leaked.

A possible incentive to install the same cert+key on all machines is to use cert pinning (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning)